# Is a diffeomorphism between two regular surfaces in $\mathbb{R}^3$ the restrictiction of a diffeomorphism between two open sets?

Tags: differential-geometry

Let $S_1,S_2\subseteq \mathbb{R}^3$ regular surfaces and $f:S_1 \rightarrow S_2$ diffeomorphism. Does this imply that there exist $A,B$ open sets in $\mathbb{R}^3$ and a diffeomorphism $F:A\rightarrow B$, such that $S_1\subseteq A$, $S_2\subseteq B$ and $\left.F\right|_{S_1}=f$?

Comment: The answer is not, check the first answer here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1942472/can-a-diffeomorphism-between-submanifolds-be-extended-to-a-self-diffeomorphism-o

Comment: @Ludwik:  The OP is only looking for a diffeo on a neighborhood, so I don't think the answers in that link directly answer this question.

Comment: What are you thoughts?  What have you tried?  For what it's worth, I believe the answer is yes, as a consequence of the existence of tubular neighborhoods.